# Lodash-es with Typescript and Webpack module error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, lodash

I want to use lodash-es to be able to import only the functions I need, but I get an error.

```
import { camelCase } from "lodash-es";
//...
console.log(camelCase('Foo'));
```

Error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'lodash-es' in '/Users/...

Browser console error

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'lodash-es'
> at webpackMissingModule..

My package.json

```
...
"devDependencies": {
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.178",
"@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.5",
```

Using normal lodash I have no problems, but the library is too big for my purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need `lodash-es` (or `lodash`) in your dependecies. You can import individual functions like this:

```
import camelCase from "lodash-es/camelCase";
```

to keep the bundle size low. `@types/*` packages are just type definitions.

Also, some functions can be installed isolated from the rest:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.camelcase